# Transmission stuck in neutral

Tags: manual-transmission, oldsmobile

I just recently bought a 1968 Oldsmobile 442 with a brand new transmission put in it. The guy I bought it from said there’s about 1200 miles on it but a few weeks after I bought the car I got in it to drive and the car wouldn’t shift out of neutral. The clutch feels right but it just sits there. Anybody have any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 4):

This first thing I suspect is the shifter linkage. If it's come loose then it won't move the gears in the transmission. Pull the boot up around the shifter and inspect and or inspect from under the car.

Comment: Pulling up the shifter boot typically wont show you much if it still has the Muncie. Check the shifter manufacturers (most likely Hurst) website for adjustment instructions.